# Retrieving user info in an OAuth2 auth flow having only an access token

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm getting a Bearer access token passed to my restful service on the Authorization header. I'm trying to retrieve some basic information like email address from the account having only the access token.

According to the google oauth java client documentation it can be done like this:

```
 GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
    Plus plus = Plus.builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory())
        .setApplicationName("Google-PlusSample/1.0")
        .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
        .build();
```

Found it here:

```
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Overview
```

First, I can't seem to be able to resolve the Plus class. Where is it located? I can't find anywhere in the documentation where it's coming from. Jars resolved through Maven don't seem to have that class. What am I missing?

Edit: Found where the Plus class was hiding. I am however still not sure how to actually get any useful information back, having just the access token.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
  <version>v1-rev115-1.17.0-rc</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it's done:

```
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token);
        Plus plus = new Plus.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
            .setApplicationName("Awesome Project")
            .build();
            plus.people().get("me").execute());
```

What was missing was the last line.